# How to Deserialize this object JSON?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, hammock

I need deserialize a json like this:

```
{"success":true,"loggedin":false,"data":{"accessTime":1285167129}}
```

My objects are:

```
public class Heartbeat
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public bool Loggedin { get; set; }

    public HeartbeatData Data { get; set; }
}

public class HeartbeatData
{
    public int AccessTime { get; set; }
}
```

But HeartbeatData doesn´t serialize.

Comment: What language is that? (And where is the code for deserialization?)

Comment: Csharp, I am using framework hammock2. This uses ServiceStack.Text to Deserialize. I think that change to Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: With some deserializers, you have to mark classes as `[Serializable]` for it to work..

Answer (score 1):

Try using [JSON.net](http://nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json) to see if that will work, then we see if it's Hammock or C# causing the issue.